# How to change dropdown value from another dropdown via Context

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I am trying to change the value of the TreatmentEditor dropdown when I select an option in the TitleEditor dropdown editor via Context but for some reason, the name variable is not set and I can't figure out why. What am I missing here and how can I change the value successfully via Context?

Here is my editors.jsx:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { DropDownList } from '@progress/kendo-react-dropdowns';
import { patients, treatments, rooms, therapists } from './data';

const EditorContext = React.createContext({
  name: '',
  setName: () => {},
});

export const TitleEditor = (props) => {
  const { name, setName } = React.useContext(EditorContext);
  const value = treatments[0];
  console.log(name);

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    if (props.onChange) {
      props.onChange.call(undefined, {
        value: value,
      });
    }
    setName(treatments[0]);
  };
  return (
    <DropDownList
      onChange={handleChange}
      value={patients.find((p) => p.id === props.value)}
      data={patients}
      dataItemKey={'id'}
      textField={'name'}
    />
  );
};
export const TreatmentEditor = (props) => {
  const selectedItem = treatments.filter((product) => product.value === 138)[0];

  const [name, setName] = React.useState('');
  const value = { name, setName };

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setName(event.target.value);
  };
  return (
    <EditorContext.Provider value={value}>
      <DropDownList
        onChange={handleChange}
        value={name}
        data={treatments}
        dataItemKey={'value'}
        textField={'text'}
      />
    </EditorContext.Provider>
  );
};
export const TherapistEditor = (props) => {
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    if (props.onChange) {
      props.onChange.call(undefined, {
        value: event.value.value,
      });
    }
  };
  return (
    <DropDownList
      disabled={true}
      onChange={handleChange}
      value={therapists.find((t) => t.value === props.value)}
      data={therapists}
      dataItemKey={'value'}
      textField={'name'}
    />
  );
};
```

and here is a runnable example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-wgynpr-ed7adj?file=app/editors.jsx